# Creating a contact in Android / iOS / Desktop from a weblink

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, npm

I am new to coding so please bear with me -

I am trying to save a contact just like we do on WhatsApp.
Consider the scenario - When we share a contact on WhatsApp, we get 2 options to "Save Contact" and "Message" the contact so when we click on save contact it directly opens the contact in our phone list, and thus we can save it.

I want to achieve the same event - I have a web link which when clicked opens a Visiting card on the browser. Now when I click on save contact it gets downloaded first in the .vcf format and then it needs to be opened again to save in the contact list, can I bypass the same by directly saving it in the phone contact list without downloading it or by downloading it in the background. I want to make this work both in Android and iOS. Any feedback/suggestion will be of great help, thanks in advance.
from webpage on click event, in which contact save directly to phone (android and ios) without downloading that file.

I am unable to make it on click file goes for download and then open that file we able to save contact.

To implement the current state I have used this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcards-js

Do let me know if any other detail is required from my end.